# Ignoring UIDs altogether with NFS - creating a publicly accessible NFS share

Tags: nfs

I have an NFS share that only two people have access to, and I cannot get their NFS clients to map the exported share on the server because of permissions. From what I've researched, this is because of UIDs having to match, etc. How can I just completely ignore this entire functionality of NFS so that it always works? I am currently using `(rw,all_squash,subtree_check)` for my exports, but getting permission errors.

The UID on both clients are different than what's on the server and I don't want to have to set up separate accounts, etc. I am just simply trying to create a "publicly" accessible shared folder, but NFS seems to make this extremely complicated.

Here's an example of the folder I've created on the server

```
[root:pivot:~]# showmount -e <ip>
Export list for <ip>:
/              *
/root/test_folder (everyone)
[root:pivot:~]# mount -t nfs <ip>:/root/test_folder test
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <ip>:/root/test_folder
```

As shown above, it should have permissions for everyone, but yet I still get permission denied when trying to mount it. I don't understsand why this is the case.

I have even given chmod 777 to the `test_folder` folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2      777 root        4096 Apr 10 17:54 test_folder
```

I have even tried to give `nobody:nogroup` ownership of the folder, assuming that NFS will map the UIDs to `nobody`

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody   nogroup     4096 Apr 10 17:54 test_folder
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/root`? They are usually 0700. Also, you shouldn't be sharing from root's home directory.